# Filter in Sparql query not working

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am running a sparql query against one of my sparql end point that supports only Sparql 1.0.

I am trying to get a list of users from store using following query :

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX tmp: <http://example.com/schema/temp#>
PREFIX resource: <http://example.com/2010/record/schema#>
Describe ?userURI
WHERE 
{
    ?userURI rdf:type resource:User.
    OPTIONAL
    {               
        ?userURI tmp:dataCleanupStatus ?cleanUpStatus.
        ?userURI tmp:lastDataCleanupDate ?cleanUpDate.                  
    }
    FILTER 
    ( 
        (!bound(?cleanUpStatus) || ?cleanUpStatus !="Running")
    )
                    FILTER(    
        (!bound(?cleanUpDate) || ?cleanUpDate < "2012-04-11" )
    )

}
```

With the above query I am trying to get users, where :

1. Either clean up status triple does not exists, or, status is not "Running"
2. clearnUpDate triple either does not exists or, is less than the specified date.

it's not returning the record it should be returning. 

You might say I should use **xsd** functions, but, they are only supported in Sparql 1.1

Please advice.

**Modified Query:**

---

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX tmp: <http://example.com/schema/temp#>
PREFIX resource: <http://example.com/2010/record/schema#>
Describe ?userURI
WHERE 
{
    ?userURI rdf:type resource:User.
    OPTIONAL
    {               
        ?userURI tmp:dataCleanupStatus ?cleanUpStatus.

    }

    OPTIONAL
    {               
        ?userURI tmp:lastDataCleanupDate ?cleanUpDate.                  
    }
    FILTER 
    ( 
        !bound(?cleanUpStatus) || ?cleanUpStatus !="Running"
    )
    FILTER
    (    
        !bound(?cleanUpDate) || ?cleanUpDate < "2012-04-11" 
    )

}
```

### ---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably in the date comparison, assuming that it's stored as an `xsd:date` typed literal in the original data. You cannot compare strings to dates without type conversion.

Some things to try:

```
?cleanUpDate < "2012-04-11"^^xsd:date    # Compare against date
STR(?cleanUpDate) < "2012-04-11"         # Convert to string before comparison
```

Also, depending on the structure of the data, you might need two separate `OPTIONAL` blocks for the `?cleanUpStatus` and `?cleanUpDate`.

Comment: actually I can't use xsd:date, as they are part of Sparql 1.1 and my end point only supports 1.0... Also, I am storing them as string literal.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I modified the query as per your suggestion, and so far it seems to working fine.

Comment: Just for the record, `xsd:date` typed literals as used in my example are part of SPARQL 1.0 and widely supported. You're probably thinking of the date/time manipulation and comparison functions that were added in SPARQL 1.1.

Comment: what ontology I need to you in case of I want to use xsd:date? I am actually storing dates as string literal...

Comment: You don't need to use any ontology. It's a built-in datatype in RDF. You just need to declare the `xsd` prefix, that's all. If your question is about the namespace URI for the `xsd` prefix, just look it up on [prefix.cc](http://prefix.cc/).